# Get records between 2 custom varchar date values

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Got a column "month_year" (varchar(10)) in one of my tables, and i have this query

```
select *
from costs 
where month_year>='06/2011'
and month_year<='10/2012'
```

I want to show the rows that have month_year values between those two, but the query seems to ignore the year part and is giving me ALL the rows that are between those two months, this query is inside a stored procedure that receives a @min_month_year and @max_month_year parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not very good design to store `date` values in `varchar` columns
But you can do something like this

```
select *
from costs 
where
    convert(datetime, '01/' + month_year, 103) >='20110601' and
    convert(datetime, '01/' + month_year, 103) < '20121101'
```

but indexes on you month_year column will not work.
If you really want to store `month_year` as a `varchar`, I suggest you to store it like `YYYYMM` - `'201106'` and `'201210'` (`'2011/06'` and `'2012/10'` if you really like `'/'`). In this case you can compare it without converting.

Comment: Thanks, now since i want to avoid changing all of my code to fit the a new format, i want to know if doing something like these 
select *
from costos 
where right(mes_año,4)+left(mes_año,2)>=right('09/2010',4)+left(09/2010,2)
and right(mes_año,4)+left(mes_año,2<=right('09/2012',4)+left(09/2010,2)
will be the same as the last part of your answer.

Comment: yes you can do this with substrings. I hope `mes_año` is `month_year` (in Spanish? :) )